# C# can't reach Enum class variables

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have created the following class:

```
namespace com.censureret.motions
{
    public class EnumPlayerStances {
        public const int OneHandSword = 50;

        /// <summary>
        /// Friendly name of the type
        /// </summary>
        public static string[] Names = new string[] {
            "One handed Sword"
            };
    }
}
```

Now I wish to use this in my following class:

```
namespace com.censureret.motions{
    public class OneHandSword_Idle : MotionControllerMotion
    {
        public override bool TestActivate()
        {
            if (!mIsStartable) { return false; }
            if (!mMotionController.IsGrounded) { return false; }

            if (mActorController.State.Stance != EnumPlayerStances.OneHandSword)

                return false;
        }

    }
}
```

However Visual Studio says it's an error.

I'm fairly new to C#. What can I try next?

Comment: What type is "mActorController.State.Stance"? You are comparing it to the const int on the EnumPlayerStances class. It looks like that class could be refactored to be more userfriendly. What does the value 50 represent? What other things do you expect to put in the string array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defeated the point of an enum. It should be declared and used like this:

```
using System;

namespace StackOverflow_Events
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string enumName = Enum.GetName(typeof(EnumPlayerStances), EnumPlayerStances.One_Handed_Sword).Replace("_", " ");
            int value = (int)EnumPlayerStances.One_Handed_Sword;
            var example = EnumPlayerStances.One_Handed_Sword;
            switch (example)
            {
                case EnumPlayerStances.One_Handed_Sword:
                    // do stuff
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {enumName}, Value: {value}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public enum EnumPlayerStances
    {
        One_Handed_Sword = 50
    }
}
```

Note that it's declared as "enum" not "class".

Also note, that if you declare the enum like:

```
public enum EnumPlayerStances
{
    No_Sword, // 0
    One_Handed_Sword, // 1
    Two_Handed_Sword // 2
}
```

The value of the first name begins at 0 and autoincrements by 1 for each following name.

Comment: I don't think that answers anything. It *can* be declared as an enum, but it does not have to. Accessing a constant as `EnumPlayerStances.OneHandSword` should work fine. Also `GetName` will return `OneHandSword` as opposed to `One handed Sword`.

Comment: I'd be doing a disservice to suggest anything other than this. Sure you can use the butt of a screwdriver to hammer in a nail. Or a class with a const field as an enum. But when you ask professionals for help you are implicitly asking "what is best, or at least reasonable, practice". And then there is only 1 good answer to give. A hammer for nails, and an enum for enumerations.

Comment: I don't see what property of enums would allow them to be reached when a constant could not be. Sure enums is a better way of organizing certain types of constants, and advice on using them should be given, but they are not any better when it comes to scope/accessibility issues the OP is apparently having. They will declare an enum instead of the constant, and will change their question to "C# can't reach Enum members"...

Comment: Thank you for your responses guys. The above code is for Unity. is it possible that these work in a different way?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Why not update the question with the error message you're getting? Because your original code is actually fine, assuming that `mActorController.State.Stance` is an `int`. Also, you might clarify your question a little, since you are referring to `Enum` a few times but not using one.